# Pandas pd.read_sql_query does not return the datetime/timestamp correctly (missing seconds)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy, sqlanydb

Running the following query via pandas:

```
conn = sqlanydb.connect( userid='xx', password='xx', eng='xx', commlinks='tcpip{host=xx port=xx}' )
query = '''select top 20 log_ts  from my_table'''
sql_output = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, parse_dates=['log_ts'])
```

results in  log_ts:  `2020-08-28 18:08:00`

However the correct format (when checking the database UI) is  `2020-08-28 18:08:57.752000`

I also tried `pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, parse_dates={'log_ts': {'format': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'])` and couldn't get it worked.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need MySQL v5.6.4+ for fractional seconds support.

Also, you need to not use the default sqlalchemy datetime type, you need to override the argument with the MySQL specific DATETIME type with defined milliseconds.

```
dtype={'date_time': DATETIME(fsp=6) }
```

Comment: Looks like my version does not support `fsp` argument for `DATETIME`.

Comment: from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import DATETIME
is where you find the DATETIME item

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, when I cast it to `TIME` only it gives me the seconds (no dates though). But when I cast it to `DATETIME` it ignores the seconds.

So, I can have the original column (without second) and have another column casted as `TIME` and merge them in python (post processing). It's not an efficient solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Might be your formatting missing the milliseconds. How about something like below.

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2020-08-28 18:08:57.752000', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f' )
```

Comment: The problem is `sql_output = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, parse_dates=['log_ts'])` doesn't even return the seconds. It just returns 0 seconds. I don't even need miliseconds.